# Include HTML in a Pandas DataFrame cell in the IPython Notebook?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

How can I include HTML in the table produced by a DataFrame in an IPython notebook?

For example, I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
pd.DataFrame({
    "text": ["Hello <strong>world</strong>"],
})
```

To produce a table something like:

```
<table>
  <tr><th></th><th>text</th></tr>
  <tr><th>0</th><td>Hello <strong>world</strong></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't think the pandas notebook display is really meant for that kind of thing.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried `pandas.DataFrame.to_html` See [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) for more info. For fantastic examples on using IPython Notebook to display html, svg, image etc see [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/1.x/examples/notebooks/Part%205%20-%20Rich%20Display%20System.ipynb)

Works like this on IPython Notebook;

```
from IPython.display import HTML
data = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5],'B':[6,7,8,9,10]})
h = HTML(data.to_html());h
```

Comment: looks like you might want to try `escape=False`

Comment: What is escape=False?

Comment: Yes, this solved my issue (wanting to embed a button).
"escape=False" will tell pandas to render the content as is e.g. without adding escape characters to your html.